# Bootstrap autocomplete scrollbar required for Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamic data being displayed in a textfield from a datalist. 
In chrome the data has 100-200 rows but it goes out of page.
Is there any way of getting a scrollbar with autocomplete.

I have tried:

```
style="overflow: scroll"
```

This does not work.

Any idea how I can do this? I am using bootstrap 3.

Comment: can you provide a plunkr? we may help better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure what exactly you're looking for. Let's start with this : http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/

Comment: yes, exactly this is what i am looking for. where can i get the code for it?

Comment: The code is at the bottom of the page or follow @karlipoppins link is fine.